# Accessing Reuters data from R/VBA

Tags: r, vba, reuters

I use the market QA data base and I would like to be able to access the data directly from R or vba or even another language if needed to pursue my studies. I couldn't find any API, has anyone here already done this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The 'tm' package has some worked examples. You may need to be more specific about what or of data you are targeting.